# Ion-fab-button ionBlur and ionFocus don’t work properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I add these methods to ion-fab-button

```
<ion-fab-button (ionBlur)="fadeBackgroundToNormal()" (ionFocus)="fadeBackgroundToBlack()">
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>
```

They are not fired at the right moment. The first time I click the button nothing happens. The second time I click the button (when it closes) it triggers ionFocus. Then it keeps working in that order until I click the background. Then it just stops working all together. (I tested this with console.log).

Comment: You can log it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not rely on this anymore but instead I toggled on a (click) event.

```
<ion-fab-button (click)="toggleBackground()">
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>
```

This works much better without delay.